# Android - updating progress bar with values from another thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an app that generates a maze. During the maze generation, I want to update a progress bar. However, I can't see a good way to do this. The progress bar operates on one thread while the maze generation operates on another. How do I get the two to pass a simple int back and forth? Sorry if this is a bad question, I am a beginner at all of this.

```
protected void incrementProgress() throws InterruptedException {
    generateMaze(); //Generates the maze by launching a new thread
    while(progressBarStatus < 100) {
        progressBarStatus = maze.getIntPercentDone(); //This does not get updated
        Thread.sleep(10);

        progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
            }
        });
    }
    if (progressBarStatus >= 100) { //This condition does not get met 
        Thread.sleep(100);
        progressBar.dismiss();
    }
}

/**
 * Dummy maze generation method that has a counter to simulate progress
 * @return
 */
protected void generateMaze() { //Method that builds a maze
    mazeBuilder.build(maze, Constants.SKILL_X[0], Constants.SKILL_Y[0], Constants.SKILL_ROOMS[0], Constants.SKILL_PARTCT[0]);
    try {
        mazeBuilder.buildThread.join();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        mazeBuilder.buildThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, your progressbar should be in the main thread. The maze generation can be done using Asyctask . Asynctask is an excellent way to do tasks on a different thread provided by the android framework, and has built in methods to post changes to the main thread.

You can know about AsyncTask [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [here](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) .

For a heads up, once you create a class extending Asynctask, you can

1. do the maze creation (long running task) in the doItInBackground() method,
2. and post the progress in the maze creation by calling publishProgress() periodically from the doItInBackground() method,
   and passing the progress (possibly as integer value representin
   percent complete).
3. publishProgress() actually passes the value to onProgressUpdate() method. from this method, you can post the progress update received
   to the main thread.
4. Now update the progress dialog in the main thread with the updated progress value in integer.

Comment: I've looked at some examples, however I don't understand how we can publishProgress() from mazebuilder to the activity?

Comment: updated answer. you can also read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/580172/Asynchronous-Tasks-using-AsyncTask -- another example